In Azure Databricks, what is difference between _RAW tables and _APPEND_RAW tables of Bronze-Layer
I am new to Azure Databricks and i would like to know difference between _RAW tables and _APPEND_RAW tables of Bronze-Layer.
As both are STREAMING Tables then why we need 2 separate tables.Also above tables are created via Delta Live Tables pipeline. so they are basically DLT Tables.
Thanks
Devsql

The  _RAW  tables and  _APPEND_RAW  tables in the Bronze layer of a Delta Lake architecture are used to store raw data in different formats and with different behaviors.
The  _RAW  tables are append-only and store the raw data in its original format without any modifications, while the  _APPEND_RAW  tables allow for both inserts and updates and capture changes to existing records.
The decision to use separate  _RAW  and  _APPEND_RAW  tables depends on your use case and architecture. If you only need the raw data without any modifications, you can use  _RAW  tables. If you want to capture changes over time, including updates, you can use  _APPEND_RAW  tables.
Reference: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/what-is-difference-between-raw-tables-and-append-raw-tables-of/m-p/78838#M35612
